# Identity for the Bessel function

Tags: bessel-functions

I'm sure this is easy, but I can't find it yet.

What is $J_n(-x)$? Where $J_n$ is the usual Bessel function of integer order.

In particular, I'm looking to the sum $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty J_n(-x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f_n(-1)J_n(x) $,

I want to find this $f_n(-1)$.

Comment: Shouldn't your $f$ also depend on $n$?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

From definition one can write $[1]$ $$J_n(x)={1\over \pi}\int_0^\pi \cos(n\tau-x\sin\tau)d\tau$$therefore $$J_{-n}(-x){={1\over \pi}\int_0^\pi \cos(-n\tau+x\sin\tau)d\tau\\={1\over \pi}\int_0^\pi \cos(n\tau-x\sin\tau)d\tau\\=J_n(x)}$$also$$J_{-n}(x)=(-1)^nJ_n(x)$$finally$$J_n(-x)=(-1)^nJ_n(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function):

$$
\lambda^{-\nu} J_\nu(\lambda z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\left( \frac{(1-\lambda^2)z}{2} \right)^n J_{\nu+n}(z)
$$

Hence, picking $\lambda = -1$:

$$
(-1)^{-\nu} J_\nu(- z) =  J_{\nu}(z)
$$